# Estimation of conditional probability

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

The joint frequency distribution of two discrete random variables,  and , is given in the following table
[image]

a) Can anybody help me how to calculate the conditional expectation of  for a given value of : (|=). For example, similar to the formula in we have: (|=1)=Σ⋅(=|=1). Find (|=1) and

b) Calculate (|=3)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. Fixed a value of $X=x$ in the above table you will see which are the values of $Y$ (in this case for any value of $X$  you have $Y=1,2,3,4$ but it could be not necessary so, in general) and all you have to do is to calulate the conditional probability with the usual formula

Example, fix $X=3$ and you get

$$(Y|X=3)=\begin{cases}
2/31,  & \text{if $Y=1$} \\
5/31,  & \text{if $Y=2$} \\
20/31,  & \text{if $Y=3$} \\
4/31,  & \text{if $Y=4$} 
\end{cases}$$

The expectation follows as a consequence being

$$E(Y|X=x)=\Sigma_y yp(y|x)$$